# Power Automate selected item trigger for multiple selected items

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, power-automate, flow

I want to trigger a flow for the selected item in the SharePoint Online list, I have developed a flow for the selected item trigger and I could see my flow appears in the Automate section from the ribbon menu. I could see my flow and other Automate stuff when I select a single item but as soon as I select more than one time I don't see the Automate option or my flow, it disappears entire the automate menu.

I have looked at the many forums, it seems many of the folks are facing the same issue. Here is one of the example in Power platform forum: [My SharePoint list tool bar "automate" button disappear](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/My-Sharepoint-list-tool-bar-quot-automate-quot-button-disappear/td-p/921611)

It seems select item trigger works only with the single item. But if we many items to select and want to trigger the flow, how will this work?

Is there any triggers for multiple selected items to trigger the flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known limitation of **For a selected item** trigger in Power automate flow.

> This trigger allows you to start a flow for **a selected item** in a SharePoint list or library.

**Documentation**: [For a selected item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#for-a-selected-item)

This trigger does not allow selecting multiple list items and triggering the flow for each item.

Also, there is no trigger available using SharePoint connector for selecting multiple list items and triggering the flow for each item.

---

**Possible Workaround/Solution**:

1. Develop a List view command set using SPFx which will allow selecting multiple items and run HTTP triggered Power automate flow.
2. Create a HTTP triggered Power automate flow which will collect all item IDs from SPFx list view command set. Trigger child power automate flow for each list item ID.
3. Create a child power automate flow which will receive item ID from HTTP triggered Power automate flow. This flow can have common logic required for your business use case.